# Azure SQL Data Sync database provisioning failed, Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: azure-sql-database

We're using [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql) to migrate our on-prem SQL Server DBs to Azure SQL DB. Lower environments have worked just fine, and they are a cloned, scrubbed version of our production DBs. When running the sync for production, we get an error:

```
Database provisioning failed with the exception "SqlException Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:-2, Message: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. Inner exception: The wait operation timed out For more information, provide tracing ID 'redacted' to customer support."
```

The local SQL Data Sync agent runs with a service account that has `db_owner` privileges, and is the same account that runs our database migrations. We tried running the local sync agent on a separate VM, then moved to running it on our production DB server itself. All lower environments are same server specs as production.

Unfortunately the UI of the local SQL Data Sync agent won't let you adjust the command timeouts, and the config file of the agent is encrypted.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1):

The error was cryptic, but upon viewing the event logs for SQL Azure Data Sync 2.0, I saw a bigger stack trace:

> at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeTableHelper.EnableSnapshotIsolation(SqlConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.ApplyScope(SqlConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.ApplyInternal(SqlConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.Apply()

Seeing that it mentioned "EnableSnapshotIsolation", I went back to the docs to see [database requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql#general-requirements) and sure enough:

> Snapshot isolation must be enabled for both Sync members and hub.

The lower environments had snapshot isolation turned on, the production databases did not. Enabling snapshot isolation for the production DBs allowed the sync to execute.